# Interface size miniature running windows 8.1?

Tags: interface, windows

I just downloaded blender on my brand new laptop using windows 8.1 and for some reason everything in the program appears miniature. I think it has something to do with resolution but I cant figure it out.

Comment: Please add a screenshot to show the issue.

Comment: maybe DPI? `User Preferences > System > General: DPI`

Comment: Are there notebooks with 4k displays?

Comment: Do you have a qHD display?  Dell m3800 per chance?

Comment: With 2.72 there is also a `Virtual Pixel Mode` option under system settings that you can switch between native and double. You can use this with combination with DPI.